# Using return to display multiple values

Tags: javascript, return

```
function myFactorial(){

var factorial1 = this.num1*(this.num1-1)*(this.num1-2)*(this.num1-3)*(this.num1-4);

var factorial2 = this.num2*(this.num2-1)*(this.num2-2)*(this.num2-3);
return (factorial1,factorial2);

}
```

I want to show factorial1 and factorial2 separated by a comma. Please help. Thanks! :)

Comment: if it is inside function then you can return an object or an array

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this:

```
return factorial1+','+factorial2;
```

Answer (score -1):

We cannot return two values in return statement. But we can achieve like this

```
var factorial = { "factorial1": factorial1, "factorial2": factorial2  };
return factorial;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Do something

```
function myFactorial(){

     var factorial1 = this.num1*(this.num1-1)*(this.num1-2)*(this.num1-3)*(this.num1-4);

     var factorial2 = this.num2*(this.num2-1)*(this.num2-2)*(this.num2-3);
     return {factorial1: factorial1,factorial2: factorial2} ;
     // OR YOU CAN RETURN AN ARRAY
    // return [factorial1, factorial2];

}
```